# The local repo is out of date

Tags: github

Привет!
Делаю push(xcode9) на удаленный repo и мне выходит ошибка: 
The local repository is out of date. 
Make sure all changes have been pulled from the remote repository and try again.

Почитал некоторые ответы, но как-то они мне на помогли... Может кто знает как решить?

Comment: Вам необходимо сделать git pull, эта ошибка говорит, что в удалённом репозитории появились новые данные, а у вас их нет

Comment: @Komdosh, да, я делал pull и потом заново push. Но ничего не поменялось. (git pull origin <branch,git push origin <branch>)

Comment: fast-forward отработал? или merge сломался?

Comment: починили... пулл-мерж-пуш через sourceTree.